# Appcelerator Build Crashes for Titanium SDK BELOW 6.0.0 GA

Tags: build, crash, appcelerator

I installed appcelerator studio  on 16/04/2018 and created a default project with choosing  Titanium SDK 5.5.1 GA. When I tried building the project, it was not proceeding after 'Packing application' (i.e) towards 'Building java source files'. But the build was completed successfully when I changed the Titanium SDK to 6.0.0 GA. Likewise when I changed the SDK to next higher versions, the build happens. My current Java SDK is 1.8.0_131. Requesting for any assistance.

Comment: Did you check the compatibilty matrix against what versions to use of everything

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the Late reply. I had resolved the issue, The problem is with the Android SDK Tools/Platform tools. I was supposed to use Android SDK Tools/ SDK Platform tools that are compatible with Android SDK 23.But I was using most recent versions. Now that I switched back to the old versions of the Tool/Platform tools, the issue is resolved. thanks for your reply as well

Comment: Great! In that case I recommend you remove the question